# What does this regular expression do?

Tags: .net, regex

Can someone please summarise what this regular expression will do?

```
ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9'.\s\-&\(\)]*$"
```

Is there any online tools that can summarise this?

Comment: Basically it allows only the characters that are inside the brackets, disregarding the length of the string.

Comment: `Stackoverflow` is your `online tool`, just put your regex in question and  get the details by experts :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` and `$` are anchors that anchor the epxression to the start and the end of the string.

`[a-zA-Z0-9'.\s\-&\(\)]` is a character class that allows any of the characters inside the `[]`

`a-z` is a character range (- is the range operator here), meaning all characters from a to z.

`\s` is a whitespace character (space, tab, newline)

`\(` is a literal `(`, `\` is for escaping

`*` is a quantifier that allows 0 or more characters inside the character class.

That means your regex can match an empty string or a string consisting only of characters from inside your character class.

Comment: What if I want to include the characters `%` and `+`, do I need to escape those?

Comment: @DaveDev Not inside the character class, you can just add them. like this `[a-zA-Z0-9'.\s\-&\(\)%+]`

Comment: @stema You dont need to escape "+"?

Comment: @DocWiki not when it is inside a character class. You only need to escape very few characters inside `[]`, only those that has special meanings inside such a class like `^` at the beginning, or `-` in the mid. Here `[a-zA-Z0-9'.\s&()%+-]` would be fine.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the -

> Is there any online tools that can summarise this?

Try - http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

You can type in a RegEx then hover over the relevant bits and it will explain what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

The [Regular Exprression Analyzer](http://xenon.stanford.edu/~xusch/regexp/analyzer.html) outputs [this](http://xenon.stanford.edu/~xusch/regexp/analyzer.html?regex=%5E%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%27.%5Cs%5C-&%5C%28%5C%29%5D%2a%24&env=env_java):

```
Parse Result:  Success!
- Sequence: match all of the followings in order
    -  BeginOfLine
    -  Repeat
          - AnyCharIn[ a to z A to Z 0 to 9 ' . WhiteSpaceCharacter - & ( )]
          - zero or more times
- EndOfLine
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>There's an error in it, I'd say. The period, which matches any character, should probably be escaped to match only the character `.`... Otherwise, it will match any line.</strike>

Assuming that the period is escaped, it will match a line containing only letters, numbers, `'`s, `.`s, whitespace, `-`s, `&`s and parenthesis, but any number or combination of these.

Comment: I'm not sure about this because I've tested this for characters, such as `+`, `%` and `^`, and all of those are caught.

Comment: You don't need to escape the dot inside a character class.

Comment: Really? Wow, I've been escaping it without need for _years_. Thanks for the enlightenment! :D

Answer (score 0):

This regex is for exact match if there is any content in the string, or it will match if the string is empty. `^` means match from start and `$` match till end of string. they are called `anchors`

this `[]` is called `character class`, every thing inside is allowable in string.

by the way above regex can be more simplified as `(?i)^[a-z0-9'.\s\-&\(\)]$`. `(?i)` is `ignore case flag` for `in-case sensitive match`